# probability question: please let me know how to approach this problem

Tags: probability

Assume that 1% of the population are musicians and that 10% of the total population is left-handed. A recent survey of musicians reveals that 60% of them are left-handed. What is the probability that a left-handed toddler will be a musician?

1. 10%
2. 6%
3. 60%
4. 50%

Comment: Please rewrite your title to be *informative*.  Your title says nothing whatsoever about the problem at hand and hence will draw fewer potential solvers and make it hard indeed for later searchers to find such a problem.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Please include your own thoughts and the effort made thus far, so that people can work with you accordingly. (Please add those in the body of the question instead of commenting.)

Comment: Use Bayes theorem

Answer (score 2):

It helps to denote events with symbols.

So denote by $A$ the musicians and by $B$ the left-handed people.
You are given that $P(A)= 0.01$ , $P(B)=0.1$ , $P(B|A) = 0.6$.

You are looking for $P(A|B)$ , can you take this from here?

Comment: ..... using Bayes' rule.